# Not able to insert a sub document in all the documents in a db using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to insert a sub document into all existing documents in a collection in db,in nodejs using express framework.Following is the code snippet:

```
updatedoc: function(update,options,cb)
{
   return this.update({},update,options).exec(cb); 
}
```

where parameters update and options are as follows :

```
const update = { $push: { "defaultads": content }};
const options = { multi: true};
```

It seems to run and gives the following output on the console :
    `{ n: 1, nmodified: 1, ok: 1 }`

but no push takes place at all ,in any of the documents of the database.
I have checked :
1) whether i am pushing in the right db.
2) whether correct values are being passed 
However I am not able to find where I am going wrong.

I am new to nodejs and would really appreciate guidance in solving this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: checkout my answer let me know if you have any queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving a simple code with full fledged requirement of yours. First create a `config.js` using this file you will be connected to mongodb.Here is the code

```
module.exports = {
    'secretKey': '12345-67890-09876-54321',
    'mongoUrl' : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/product'
}
```

Next create a `models` folder . Keep this schema in this models folder . I named it as `product.js`. Here is the code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var imageSchema = new Schema({
imagepath:{
    type:String
}
});
var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

productName:{type: String},
productPrice:{type: Number},
imagePaths:[imageSchema]
});
module.exports  = mongoose.model("product", nameSchema);
```

Next create a `routes` folder and keep this routes code in this folder I named it as `route.js`. Here is the code

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Product = require('../models/product');
var app = express();
var Router = express.Router();
Router.use(bodyParser.json());

Router.get('/product',function(req,res){
 Product.find({}, function (err, product) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(product);
    });
})  
Router.post('/productData',function(req, res, next){
    Product.create(req.body, function (err, product) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Product Data created!');
        var id = product._id;

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.end('Added the product data with id: ' + id);
    });    
})

Router.post('/subdocument',function (req, res, next) {
Product.find({},function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
        result[i].imagePaths.push(req.body);
        result[i].save(function (err, ans) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('SubDocument created!');
          });
        }
        res.send("Successfully added");
    });
})  
    module.exports = Router;
```

Next server code I named it as `app.js`. Here is the code

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Product = require('./models/product');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config');
mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
});
var app = express();
var route=require('./routes/route');
app.use('/route',route);
    app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Server listening on 3000");
});
```

Run the server as `node app.js`.

**API's**

1. Use `GET` method `http://localhost:3000/route/product` .This is for getting all the product information.
2. Use `POST` method `http://localhost:3000/route/productData` .This for creating document. Post data in json format through request body like

   {

   "productName" : "sweets",
   "productPrice" : "33"

   }

You will see the response like this.

[image]
First post some documents i.e., post 2 or 3 documents and then you can see the documents with `get API` as I mentioned above. Then you will see all the documents contains empty sub document. You will see the response like this

[image]

And now add the sub document to all using the below api.

3. Use `POST` method `http://localhost:3000/route/subdocument` . Using this you can add a sub document to all the documents like this you need to add sub document

   {

   "imagepath" : "desktop"

   }

You can see the response like this

[image]

After this again when you run the `get API` you can see all the sub documents are added to all documents.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for putting in so much of efforts :), How ever I have done as above ,but it just gets first document in the database in the result and does not enter in any document:(. .Where am i going wrong? its pretty straight forward.

Comment: Any ways, I have resolved the issue . My code is working now :) Thank you for your help Syeda Ayesha Bebe

Comment: Ayesha Bebe -Your answer did not help me to solve my problem .if you want it to be accepted just for the sake of it . then fine .

Comment: This code is as per your requirement why this code doesn't help you is this is not your requirement?????